# Vue.js are not displaying images from Django media folder

Tags: django, vue.js, django-media

So, i have up and running Django server on localhost. There's is a Vue page, whick is authorized and able to fetch models data.
If i inspect page, i see that img element have correctly resolved URL, and image exsists and can be loaded.

[image: But I got this:]
As you can see, other model parameters (such as name and price) can be loaded.
[image: Page source code]

```
def get_thumbnail(self):
        if self.thumbnail:
            return 'http:://127.0.0.1:8000/' + self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            if self.image:
                self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
                self.save()

                return 'http:://127.0.0.1:8000/' + self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                return ''
```

Here's how I loading img.

```
<figure class="image mb-4">
            <img v-bind:src="product.get_thumbnail" />
</figure>
```

I've checked media folder paths, and believe they are correct

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

Also, if I am able to load image by the link gotten via page inspection, why can't it be loaded on page itself?

UPDATE:

I found the problem:
[when I'm pointing at src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdYDR.png)

Comment: Add your Product models and get_thumbnail method, usually the get_thumbnail should return the url of image so check the source code in the browser how rendered

Comment: Added get_thumbnail and page source code screenshot

Comment: Does ctrl clicking on the link of the src attribute give you an image?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's why I'm stuck

Comment: So, for some reason link to IMG generated from get_thumbnail looks like this - http://localhost:8080/://127.0.0.1:8000//'

Comment: Sorry I forget you :). But I don't know maybe the problem solved vu I think your generated url is wrong the correct address something like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img.jpg` . But in your code the url in the middle have duplicate slash like this `http://128.0.0.1:800//media` , and after that the correct syntax of http is 'http://' no 'http:://'